# How do you stop a method from running when you call another one?

Tags: python, pygame

When calling `win.instructionScreen(screen, win)`, the instructions screen appears but the text from startScreen remains. Using `screen.fill(BLACK)` does not work because the main loop causes the text in `startScreen` to reappear, and using `return` to stop the `startScreen` method does not work.

```
import pygame

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tickets = 0

    def startScreen(self, screen, win):
        titleText = pygame.font.SysFont('Showcard Gothic', 60)
        subText = pygame.font.SysFont('Showcard Gothic', 20)

        text = titleText.render("Our Game", True, WHITE)
        cs = subText.render("Final Project", True, WHITE)
        names = subText.render("Name 1, Name 2, Name 3, Name 4", True, WHITE)

        screen.blit(text, [220, 200])
        screen.blit(cs, [310, 265])
        screen.blit(names, [150, 290])

        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if 493 > mouse[0] > 343 and 461 > mouse[1] > 411:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, (343, 411, 150, 50))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, (343, 411, 150, 50))

        buttonText = pygame.font.SysFont('Showcard Gothic', 30)

        start = buttonText.render("Start!", True, WHITE)
        screen.blit(start, [365, 425])

        for event in pygame.event.get():
             if 494 > mouse[0] > 343 and 461 > mouse[1] > 411:
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    win.instructionScreen(screen, win)
                    pygame.display.update()
                    return

        pygame.display.update()

    def instructionScreen(self, screen, win):

        background = pygame.image.load("background.png").convert()
        screen.blit(background, [0, 0])
        caption = pygame.image.load("caption.png").convert()
        oak = pygame.image.load("oak.png").convert()
        oak.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        screen.blit(oak, [570, 130])
        titleText = pygame.font.SysFont('Showcard Gothic', 60)
        subText = pygame.font.SysFont('Showcard Gothic', 25)

        text = titleText.render("Instructions", True, WHITE)
        captionText = subText.render("Hey! Welcome to our game! Start by walking up", True, BLACK)
        captionText2 = subText.render("to and playing Higher or Lower and racking up", True, BLACK)
        captionText3 = subText.render("tickets. Then, when you get enough tickets,", True, BLACK)
        captionText4 = subText.render("different games will be unlocked. Have fun!", True, BLACK)

        screen.blit(text, [200, 80])

        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if 480 > mouse[0] > 325 and 550 > mouse[1] > 500:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, (325, 500, 150, 50))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, (325, 500, 150, 50))

        buttonText = pygame.font.SysFont('Showcard Gothic', 30)

        screen.blit(caption, [3, 300])
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (45, 320, 670, 110))

        screen.blit(captionText, [45, 325])
        screen.blit(captionText2, [45, 350])
        screen.blit(captionText3, [45, 375])
        screen.blit(captionText4, [45, 400])

        play = buttonText.render("Play!", True, WHITE)
        screen.blit(play, [357, 515])

        #if 480 > mouse[0] > 325 and 550 > mouse[1] > 500:
        #    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        #        from gamescreen.py import gamescreen

        pygame.display.update()

    def clearScreen(self, screen):
        screen.fill(WHITE)

def main():
    pygame.init()
    size = [800, 600]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Arcade City")
    done = False
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    win = Game()
    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                done = True

        win.startScreen(screen, win)
        clock.tick(60)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

It's easier if you don't use nested functions. Call `win.InstructionScreen()` from the main function instead of from the method `win.startScreen()`. Use state variables to control the flow and return which state it should be from the methods.

```
win = Game()
current_screen = 'start'
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            done = True
    if current_screen == 'start':
        current_screen = win.startScreen(screen, win)
    elif current_screen == 'instruction':
        current_screen = win.instructionScreen(self, screen, win)
    clock.tick(60)
```

This is just a mock-up, so you'll you have to change the methods after your own fittings. Put a return statement in both methods so they always return what the current screen should be.

**TIP:**
Instead of loading in your images and fonts every frame you could load them in the `__init__` method and save them in a attribute variable.

**EDIT:**
To answer your actual question: You cannot stop an outer method to run. Think of it this way: You have a box in a room; can you get the box without entering the room? No. You have an inner method inside an outer method; can you get the inner method without entering the outer method? No.

If you only want the inner method to run without the outer method to be run, you have to call the inner method directly and not call the outer method.